# How to convert String into List of dynamic in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a flutter project with firebase.
When I tried to fetch data `({id: 2021-10-13 04:48:15.582, title: Red Shirt, quantity: 1, price: 29.99}, {id: 2021-10-13 04:48:19.438, title: Mobile Phone, quantity: 1, price: 215})`

So, I want to convert each map to a list of dynamic because I got this error

> Error: Expected a value of type 'List< dynamic>', but got one of type 'String'

here is my code to fetch data

```
Future<void> fetchandSetOrders() async {
const url = "https://test-app.firebaseio.com/orders.json";
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
final List<OrderItem> loadedOrders = [];
final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
if (extractedData == null) {
  return;
}
extractedData.forEach((orderId, orderData) {
  print(orderData['products']);
  print(orderData['products'].runtimeType);

  loadedOrders.add(
    OrderItem(
      id: orderId,
      amount: orderData['amount'],
      dateTime: DateTime.parse(orderData['dateTime']),
      products: (orderData['products'] as List<dynamic>)
          .map(
            (item) => CartItem(
              id: item['id'],
              price: item['price'],
              quantity: item['quantity'],
              title: item['title'],
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
    ),
  );
});
_orders = loadedOrders.reversed.toList();
notifyListeners();}
```

Comment: What data is inside orderData['products']?

Comment: @ThiagoCarvalho As I mentioned, it returns ({id: 2021-10-13 04:48:15.582, title: Red Shirt, quantity: 1, price: 29.99}, {id: 2021-10-13 04:48:19.438, title: Mobile Phone, quantity: 1, price: 215}) which means the actual data but as String.

Comment: Please, add more data for example; OrderItem class detail, orderData raw data, _orders variable initialize point etc.